# changing java style iterator to foreach or Lambda style

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, resharper

i want to change all java style iterator in my code to foreach or Lambda style.

i want to do that by adding code snippet to the Resharper.
and then-
as foreach for example when you write the word foreach and click Tab Tab the all foreach expression  written.
-so the all iterator expression will be change to foreach or Lambda.

any way,
if you know how to change iterator to foreach or Lambda style, it will help me a lot!

**i need to change this code block to foreach or Lambda**:

```
IEnumerator xIntEnumerator = xList.GetEnumerator();
while (xIntEnumerator.MoveNext())
{ 
            //do somthing
            }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With ReSharper 5 you can try to use Structured Patterns to accomplish your task. Check [this article](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2010/04/introducing-resharper-50-structural-search-and-replace/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
foreach (var x in xList) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: He is asking for resharper macro. He knows how foreach works.

Comment: yea, i am asking for resharper macro. Thanks!!